# Blackjack python dice game fix?

Tags: python, blackjack

When someone says something else in replay() except for "no" or "yes" it starts the host's turn for some reason or even no.

I'm still learning, this is my second project, any comments?
I tried many things but it still doesn't work.

```
# Blackjack game

import random

global playername, nameofplayer
nameofplayer = input('Enter your name').capitalize()
print ('Hello,', str(nameofplayer))

class Player():
    def __init__(self, banktotal):
        self.banktotal = banktotal

    # adds an amount to the bank

    def addtobank(self, bankadd):
        self.banktotal += bankadd

    # removes an amount from the bank

    def subfrombank(self, subbank):
        self.banktotal -= subbank




def rolldice():
    global playerhand
    playerhand = 0
    print('Your Current hand: ' + str(playerhand))
    playerhand = 0
    print ('...')
    print ('Rolling the dice for you')
    dice = list(range(1,7))
    while playerhand <= 21:
        rolled = random.choice(dice)

        print('Your Current hand: ' + str(playerhand))

        hitstick = str(input('Hit or Stick?').capitalize())
        if hitstick == 'Hit':
             print('You chose to hit!')
             playerhand += rolled

        elif hitstick == 'Stick':
            print('Your exit hand: ' + str(playerhand))
            break
        elif hitstick != 'Hit' or 'Stick':
            print('Enter a valid argument')




    else:
        print('Your Current hand: ' + str(playerhand))

        print ('Busted, Host Wins!')
        print('Reducing 100$ from your account')
        playername.banktotal -= 100
        print('Your bank balance: ' + str(playername.banktotal))

        replay()




def hostchance():
    hosthand = 0
    print ('Current host hand: ' + str(hosthand))
    dice = list(range(1, 7))

    while hosthand <= playerhand:

        rolled = random.choice(dice)
        hosthand += rolled
        print('Rolling the dice for the host')
        print ('Current host hand: ' + str(hosthand))
        if hosthand < playerhand:
            pass
        elif hosthand == playerhand:
            print ('Its a draw!')
            break
        elif hosthand > playerhand and hosthand < 22:
            print('Host Wins!')
            print('Reducing 100$ from your account')
            playername.banktotal -= 100
            break
    if hosthand < playerhand or hosthand > 21:
        print (str(nameofplayer) + ' Wins!')
        print('Adding 100$ to your account')
        playername.banktotal += 100




playername = Player(1000)

def game():

    print ('Your bank balance: ' + str(playername.banktotal))
    rolldice()

    something = input('Enter anything for the host to start his turn')
    print (something)

    print('Host Chance')
    hostchance()
    print ('Your bank balance: ' + str(playername.banktotal))



def replay():
    print('Do you want to play again?')
    replay = input('Input with yes or no: ').lower()


    if replay == 'yes':
        game()
    elif replay == 'no':
        pass


game()
replay()
```

Comment: What do you expect the `pass` after the `elif replay == 'no':` to actually do?

Comment: If the site asks you to add more text, do **not** repeat everything! It asks for a *reason*.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than doing `pass` after receiving a no answer, you should `exit()` or `quit()`.